# Scala - get list of bound variables?

Tags: scala, variables

Is there any way to get a list of bound variables in scala?

Comment: What are the *bound* variables?

Comment: I am using a scala interpreter, and I would like to get a list of all the global variables that are currently defined

Comment: I'm wondering if there's something similar to this solution for Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784353/python-print-names-and-values-of-all-bound-variables

Comment: Somethiing like locals() in python? Sounds good. Good question.

Comment: _bound_ variables are those with bindings! Meaning those for which a value has been established (as opposed to the countable infinity of names in any given scope that have not been given a value...).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `:power` mode in 2.9, 2.10, and 2.11 you can `intp.visibleTermNames.sorted.foreach(println)` to get everything, or `intp.definedTerms.foreach(println)` for just the things you've created.

In 2.10, `$intp` is always visible (power mode or no), so `$intp.definedTerms.foreach(println)` will print a list in non-power mode.

Try `intp.`+tab in power mode to list all the methods available.  (Symbols starting with `$` don't have tab-completion enabled.)

Comment: Yes, intp.definedTerms is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In Scala 2.10 REPL, it is possible to access instance of `IMain` associated with the REPL. It is available as `$intp`. It seems that it is possible to deeply inspect REPL state with this.

For example, `$intp.unqualifiedIds` may be helpful to you.

Comment: This is close, but it has a little too much information for me

Answer (score 4):

In the REPL you can use the `:dump` command to print the internal state of the REPL. One of the first lines should be something like:

```
Names: $ires0 $ires1 $ires2 $ires3 $ires4 $ires5 $ires6 $ires7 $r x z
```

These are all variables, classes and singletons you defined in this session.

I don't know of a way to only show the variables.

**edit**:

before the `:dump` command is available you have to enter the power mode with `:power`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That might work, except that I am unfortunately using a different interpreter which doesn't handle the same special commands